# Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class activity

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

this is my first dealing with android studio so am having some problems with my first test app.

Im successfully building my code, however as soon as i try and run it im getting this crash in logcat

```
2020-06-27 22:31:48.069 7202-7202/? I/example.testap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-06-27 22:31:48.079 7202-7202/? I/example.testap: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2020-06-27 22:31:48.081 7202-7202/? W/example.testap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-06-27 22:31:48.187 7202-7202/com.example.testapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-06-27 22:31:48.187 7202-7202/com.example.testapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-06-27 22:31:48.196 7202-7228/com.example.testapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2020-06-27 22:31:48.200 7202-7228/com.example.testapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2020-06-27 22:31:48.202 7202-7228/com.example.testapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2020-06-27 22:31:48.268 7202-7202/com.example.testapp W/example.testap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-06-27 22:31:48.269 7202-7202/com.example.testapp W/example.testap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-06-27 22:31:48.289 7202-7202/com.example.testapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
2020-06-27 22:31:48.291 7202-7202/com.example.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testapp, PID: 7202
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.testapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.testapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3356)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.testapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.testapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class activity
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.testapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class activity
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.activity
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:813)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:774)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:911)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:9)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7973)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
2020-06-27 22:31:48.291 7202-7202/com.example.testapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.activity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~_V0W6ngtaS6QvWn5yVj4bg==/com.example.testapp-EDFi4s7wfHfMG_o2gd_kKA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~_V0W6ngtaS6QvWn5yVj4bg==/com.example.testapp-EDFi4s7wfHfMG_o2gd_kKA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib, /product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 33 more
2020-06-27 22:31:48.338 7202-7202/com.example.testapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7202 SIG: 9
```

Heres the part of the androidmanifest.xml file I belive it is talking about:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/bolt_logo_2_bolt_square"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, knowing me I've probably missed something stupid lol

Edit: changed the code sample as I misread it as activity_main.xml sorry

Edit 2: sorry completely misunderstood what was meant, however from that ive fixed it. simply removed the activity from the activity_main.xml file and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The code that you have mentioned here goes in AndroidManifest.xml and not in the activity_main.xml.

Comment: Answer this question with the solution and then accept it, so it can be useful to others as well.